# How do I stop the view from wobbling when loading in & displaying data?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In this project, a user selects two sports teams to follow. The logos of these teams are displayed in the view. They are loaded via an API I made (called fetchFollowingTeams).

When the view is initialised, the view has a 'wobble' effect. All the elements in the view essentially reposition themselves slightly. I think this is due to the API taking slightly longer to load and display data than the other views.

When I comment out the code that displays the following teams data, the 'wobble' effect does not occur.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is the code:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    @StateObject var followingTeamsModel = FollowingTeamsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
       
        NavigationView {
                       
            ScrollView {
                              
                HStack {
                   
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")

                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    //MARK: Its this data / view loading that makes screen jitter
                    HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        ForEach(FollowingTeamsModel.following_teams, id: \.id) { items in
                            
                            KFImage(URL(string: "https://example.com/team_logo/\(items.logo_file ?? "")")!)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                                .padding(5)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                }
                
                VStack {
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        Text("This is my HStack view")
                    }
                    .padding(16)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
            self.followingTeamsModel.fetchFollowingTeams(key: keyString ?? "")
        })
        .animation(.easeIn)
    }
}

import Foundation
import Combine

class FollowingTeamsViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var following_teams = [FollowingTeam]()
    
    func fetchFollowingTeams(key: String) {
        
        print("Fetching Following Teams...")
        following_teams.removeAll()
        
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = "www.example.com"
        components.path = "/example_api/example_fetch_following_teams.php"
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: key)
        ]
        
        guard let url = components.url else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let todoData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([FollowingTeam].self, from: todoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.following_teams = decodedData
                    }
                    decodedData.forEach { team in
                        print(team.team_name)
                    }
                   
                } else {
                    
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I had to fill in the blanks with mock code as the code posted is missing necessary pieces. I am unable to reproduce with my best-guess of what the code should be. Could you update the code to include the missing pieces?

Comment: Do you load images in KFImage ? This could explain the problem as url fetching would be made on main thread.

Comment: @PtitXav yes I am using Kingfisher to load the images, the api returns it’s url and kingfisher handles the rest

Comment: @nickreps sure, what are the missing pieces you are referring to? The view model? Etc.

Comment: @mbby the view model seems to be missing.

Comment: @nickreps I just edited the question and added the view model